# I want to delete an incomplete comment

Tags: support, comments

I understand that comments may not be edited after some specific time limit.

My problem is that I made a partial comment but was then defeated by my connection going down.  Somewhere along the line the partial comment got posted. It doesn't make sense, as it terminates in the middle.

Is there a way that I can delete it or request someone else to do so.

If a moderator can do it for me, I'm not sure where/how to report it.

Should I make the request by flagging it in the Question or Answer that I commented on. Should I request it here?  Is there some other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the [mystery meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation) of Stack Exchange is the comment deletion mechanism.

Hovering over the comment in question will reveal options after the timestamp:

[image: Comment options]

Click the × button to remove the comment.

If you can't do that — perhaps you're using an app which conceals it even more securely — you'll need to flag something. The most obvious thing is the post (Question or Answer), but that raises a flag *against someone else.* If there's another comment which could be flagged, say a "@chasly Did you really mean to say that?" then raise a custom flag on that comment instead.

Comment: Doh!  Silly me. I never thought to hover. Thanks.